# Identify group packets?

Tags: tcp, ip, wireshark, packet-sniffers, packets

How do you identify packets based on a group? 
Such as, let's say I'm streaming a video on the internet, how do I know this packets are from a video and not something related to Google Analytics?

Considering that both the video and Google Analytics are from the same domain.

I am relative new to TCP/IP and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Such as using something like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)? Packet sniffing with the above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcp has an identifier for the packet's session. If you right click on a packet and click "follow tcp stream" it automatically filters out the chosen packet's session for you.

Comment: Is this using wireshark?

Comment: Yes it does. In Wireshark, right click on the packet that is part of thr tcp session you are interested in, and click "follow tcp stream".  It will automatically filter only the session you care about and open a new window with all the data passed in it.